# Elastic search error: "Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started"

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, startup

I pulled the elastic search image from docker and tried to run it using docker command but it didn't work. I got the following error:

> ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
>       [1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers,
>   cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
>       {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-02-10T19:47:06,566Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name":
>   "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "stopping
>   ..." }
>       {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-02-10T19:47:06,600Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name":
>   "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "stopped" }
>       {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-02-10T19:47:06,600Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name":
>   "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "closing
>   ..." }
>       {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-02-10T19:47:06,630Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name":
>   "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "closed" }
>       {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-02-10T19:47:06,633Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.NativeController",
>   "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch",
>   "message": "Native controller process has stopped - no new native
>   processes can be started" }

Comment: Can you reformate your error message and provide the image you pull

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Even your logs are not very right format, I understand that you are running Elasticsearch version: 7.x.
So here I believe you are missing the environment variable which needs to provide while running container.

In case you are running single-node Elasticsearch than add environment variable:
`discovery.type=single-node`

I would like to see your docker run command and image you are using if still this solution not works.

Comment: @saivishalvangala kindly mark and upvote the answers so that others will get the benefit.

Comment: can you tell me what it means discovery.type=single-node

Comment: this env says, elasticsearch is having only one node and a node will elect itself master and will not join a cluster with any other node.

Comment: i am getting error when i try to connect filebeat to the elastic search container. i not understanding the reason behind the error. all of my filebeat.yml apache.yml are correct.

Comment: is setting as single-node causing the connection error between filebeat and elastic search which is earlier connected to kibana

Comment: @saivishalvangala based on your early comment I can see you thanks for the solution which worked, now you are discussing something else which is a new question.  Kindly create a new question with details, sure you will get benefit from the community.  
And again my humble suggestion will mark the answer as accepted so that someone else will get benefit.

Comment: i am unable to vote the answer as my reputation score is below 15. thank you once again for help. but i can't vote for the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208754/error-while-setting-filebeat-up-and-make-it-connect-to-elastic-search

Comment: this is the link of my new question. please go through once and check is u can solve my error. thankyou

Answer (score 20):

Had the same Problem , but it in fact in the log was shown that the vm.max_map_count was set to small by default. This caused the cascading issue with the message in the end.

After using ( Linux ) my problem was solved

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

On Windows with docker desktop and WSL2 access Docker desktop :

```
 wsl -d docker-desktop
```

and then use the command above

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: thanks, this just saved me @ linux docker

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you are starting docker on your local machine with production settings.

The error message is clearly saying below params are missing

> bootstrap checks failed [1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html#_forcing_the_bootstrap_checks): the default discovery settings are
>   unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts,
>   discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be
>   configured

If you are running it locally then no need to pass these params and simply start using below command by providing the  `discovery.type=single-node` param to bypass the production checks.

> docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node"
>   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0

**EDIT:- Please go through [ES Bootstrap checks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html#_forcing_the_bootstrap_checks) to understand these params and error message in details, it would help you understand the imporatace and what these params do.**

Comment: can you tell me what it means discovery.type=single-node

Comment: i am getting error when i try to connect filebeat to the elastic search container. i not understanding the reason behind the error. all of my filebeat.yml apache.yml are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem too when I try to install **7.9.0** version of Elasticsearch on **Windows Server 2022**.
For the solution I added

> ***discovery.type: single-node***

to **elasticsearch.yml** file then run **elasticsearch.bat**  again.